# 2010 27" iMac - ambient sensor connection on cpu fan

Tags: imac, hardware

2010 27" iMac - regarding the ambient sensor connection on cpu fan housing - What is the proper contact position of the sensor with relation to the bracket that secures/holds the sensor in place?

Comment: Sharing your email address on a public website might not be the best idea...

Answer (score 1):

The image below was taken from page 238 of the [Apple Technician Guide iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010)](https://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/imac/imac_27_mid10.pdf). There are other images regarding the sensor cable in the document.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mr. Anderson,

Comment: The boy just know too much. Nice, Vote up!